# IdempotentParameterMismatchException for AWS Glue Job

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework, aws-glue, serverless

`An error occurred: MergeV2Qa - Job with name 'merge_v2_qa' already submitted with different configuration (Service: AWSGlue; Status Code: 400; Error Code: IdempotentParameterMismatchException; Request ID: 7385f6da-3c7e-4a3f-8139-d63b32351f3b).`

Getting IdempotentParameterMismatchException while creating glue job using cloudformation.

Comment: It looks like you are attempting to create a glue job with a name that is already used in the same account and region. Either change the job name in your stack, or run this in a different region or account.

Comment: check this out https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-exceptions.html#aws-glue-api-exceptions-IdempotentParameterMismatchException

Answer (score 0):

before the update

```
 GLUE_CLIENT.update_job(JobName=jobname, JobUpdate=job_config)
```

you should delete the

```
del job_config["Tags"]
del job_config["Name"]
```